# How does Noah Classifieds encrypt their passwords?

Tags: md5, decode, encryption

Here are some examples:

```
db: 35273f5c7b3fb45a
actual: 5093625

db: 272beab9517a8835
actual: 7091343
```

According to http://hash-it.net/ it's not MD5 or SHA1.

Comment: Not programming related? Again, huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got a reply from the developers:

"The native 'password' function of MySql is used to encode the passwords. You can find it in the 'getPassword' function of 'gorum/dbproperty.php'"

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is being salted, as none of the hashes on http://www.hashemall.com/ worked.
You can read more about salting [here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography))